# I am getting errors while trying to build my flutter project in android studio

Tags: flutter

When I try to run my flutter application, I get the error below. What could be the cause?
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

I am using `qr_code_scanner: ^0.5.2`,

```
      Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.7.0\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (23, 1): Class 'QRView' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.7.0\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (216, 26): Null can not be a value of a non-null type String
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.7.0\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (247, 26): Null can not be a value of a non-null type String
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.7.0\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (310, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.7.0\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRViewFactory.kt: (10, 1): Class 'QRViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.7.0\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRViewFactory.kt: (13, 5): 'create' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':qr_code_scanner:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: StarMe
description: A Social Media Project.
publish_to: "none"
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  flutter_icons_nullsafty: ^1.0.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  share: ^2.0.4
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.7.0
  fluro: ^2.0.3
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  image_picker: ^0.8.4
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.3.0
  provider: ^6.0.0
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^4.2.1
  local_auth: ^1.1.7
  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
  fl_chart: ^0.40.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  web3dart: ^2.3.1
  device_info_plus: ^2.1.0
  package_info_plus: ^1.3.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_paystack:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/definitelyme/flutter_paystack.git
      ref: a4a33c3dd0a12f46d655a2e63d11e9f20ba82d01

  flutter_braintree: ^2.0.0+1
  loading_overlay: ^0.3.0
  lazy_load_scrollview: ^1.3.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  in_app_review: ^2.0.3
  image_cropper: ^1.5.0
  ntp: ^2.0.0
  uuid: ^3.0.4
  cron: ^0.3.2
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+1
  translator: ^0.1.7

  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.9
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^3.0.1

  easy_localization_loader: ^1.0.0
  
  sentry_flutter: ^6.0.1
  twilio_phone_verify: ^2.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.0.1
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2


  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternative [mobile_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner). this library doesn't work in Flutter 3.0. or else if you want to use qr_code_scanner library, that is not the official creator repo but you can use it.

```
dependency_overrides:
    qr_code_scanner:
        git:
            url: https://github.com/X-SLAYER/qr_code_scanner.git
            ref: flutter-beta
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving `qr_code_scanner: ^0.5.2` try `qr_code_scanner: any`. This is just a workaround. It will fetch a relevant version of QR scanner automatically. If it doesn't work try `flutter clean` and then `flutter run`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried your solution, But am still getting the same error.

Comment: Is qr .scanner the only package in pubspec? Can you post the pubspec.yaml file also please? Or try adding the latest version of QR scanner 0.7.0

Comment: I have updated my error and added my pubspec.yaml file above.

Comment: Got it. Are you running this on flutter3? If yes then remove the ? From widgetBinding.instance?  Keep it without the question mark.. if you hover on these errors you should get suggestions to fix too.

Comment: Yes I am running on flutter3, I will remove the ? From widgetBinding.instance as suggested and try to run again

Comment: Thank you for your time. Though I am still getting the same error, check my updated error

Comment: Remove all packages from pubspec.yaml. Run pub get and then add all packages back and run pub get again then try flutter run. Also assuming you would have upgraded flutter through terminal the pub cache would not have been cleaned. You can run `flutter pub cache clean`. Please be noted that it will clear all pub cache so you may have to run pub get for all projects.